# How to setup a pipenv Python 3.6 project if OS Python version is 3.5?

Tags: python, pipenv

My Ubuntu 16.04.03 is installed with Python 3.5.2. How do I setup pipenv to use Python 3.6 when my system does not have python 3.6?

```
$ pipenv --python 3.6
Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Either manually write the version you need in your Pipfile:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Or install it on your system. But I guess you **will** need the version to be installed if you plan to actually run `pipenv install`.

I would suggest to use `pyenv`: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.

Follow the installation instructions, then installing Python 3.6 is just a matter of

```
pyenv install 3.6.3
```

Then you can set the order of preference with

```
pyenv global system 3.6.3
```

Besides, if `pyenv` is available, `pipenv` will automatically use it to install the required version. From `pipenv` README:

> Automatically install required Pythons, if pyenv is available.

Comment: I selected this answer because `pyenv` allowed me to install various python versions w/o affecting or conflicting with the OS Python version. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `pyenv` not installed together with `pipenv` ?

Comment: Because the choice to use pyenv is left to the user :) And using pyenv (which is a bash script) requires the user to load it in the current shell (from .bashrc for example), and pipenv does not want to do it for you I guess.

Comment: I have 3.6.5 and 3.6.6 installed, when I specified 3.6.6 in the pipfile pipenv complained that I need 3.6.5. It did not automatically switch.

Comment: @parsecer make sure to follow the latest installation instruction at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: `Automatically install required Pythons, if pyenv is available.` - can you clarify? I ran `pipenv --python 3.10` and got "Warning: Python 3.10 was not found on your system…" so that doesn't seem to automatically installed a python version (I do have pyenv installed)

Comment: This is what pipenv's README advertises. If it does not work, you definitely should open an issue on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 13):

On MacOS, I have also used [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage python versions, similar to @pawamoy's suggestion.

After installation I executed `pipenv shell` with the `--python` option pointing to the directory of the specific `pyenv` version.  This will automatically generate a `Pipfile` with `python_version = "3.6"`.

```
⇒  pipenv --python /Users/<Your User>/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/bin/python3.6 shell
```

Comment: `pipenv shell` specifying the python path it is a clever trick that simply works!

Answer (score 10):

Install 'pyenv' package by using `brew install pyenv` (if you don't have it).

Install python 3.6 using `pyenv install 3.6`

Export new installed python version to PATH

`export PATH=${PYENV_PYTHON_VERSIONS_HOME}/3.6/bin`

Now in 'Piplock' specify the same version.

`[requires]
 python_version = "3.6"`

Finally, run `pipenv install --dev`.

Comment: where to write export PATH=${PYENV_PYTHON_VERSIONS_HOME}/3.6/bin
and where to find piplock ? Please

Answer (score 5):

Install python 3.6 [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04
    If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, you can use Felix Krull's deadsnakes PPA at https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Alternatively, you can use J Fernyhough's PPA at https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04
```

If you are using Ubuntu 16.10 or 17.04, then Python 3.6 is in the universe repository, so you can just run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Then create specific version python env

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 python36venv
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS (latest version `BigSur` and `Monterey`), downloading a version of python from `pyenv` throws some error while building. So I would suggest to simply download the python installer of that version (3.6 [in your case](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-macosx10.6.pkg)) from the official site. Then use the command

```
pipenv install --python 3.6
```

PS: One of the rare moments where not using command line can save you a bit of time and frustration.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do a virtualenv of a Python version you don't have. What you can do is one of these options:

---

- If you want to test your code in several versions of Python, the right way to go is [Tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
- If you want multiples python installations available in your system, I recommend you [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) for [Python](https://github.com/tuvistavie/asdf-python).

Comment: `tox` also needs the different Python versions to be installed.