# pipenv fails to create virtual environment with pyenv python 3.8.0

Tags: python, pipenv, ubuntu-20.04, pyenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment with python 3.8.0. I'm currently using **Ubuntu 20.04**. Which has python 3.8.5 installed. So I have installed pyenv and installed python 3.8.0 as well.

### Problem:

When I run this command: `pipenv --python 3.8.0 shell` I get this error message:

```
Warning: Python 3.8.0 was not found on your system...
Would you like us to install CPython 3.8.0 with Pyenv? [Y/n]: Y
Installing CPython 3.8.0 with /home/tareq/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv (this may take a few minutes)...
✔ Success! 

Warning: The Python you just installed is not available on your PATH, apparently.
```

I have read a github issue which didn't help me. Any idea how can I solve this?

### Output of which python:

`/home/tareq/.pyenv/shims/python`

Comment: Do you need to do this with pipenv? you can try virtualenv also

Comment: Actually I work with pipenv mostly. I know virtualenv works, and I'm currently using it. But I want this issue to resolved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734041/6505847

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before that make sure which version of python you have. By python -V.Then put that version after --python. Here is the example.

```
python3 -m pipenv --python 3.8 shell
```

Also you can specify the python version location

```
python3 -m pipenv --python ~/desktop/python3.8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. The second command worked for me.

Comment: My pleasure. 